# Choosing proper Order field when using Point to Path tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, polyline-creation, points-to-line, order

I'm practicing creating vectors/lines in QGIS 3.16.3 by uploading .csv files from Excel with Lat/Long decimal degrees, and then using the "Points to Path" tool to connect the locations.

I wanted to show a path from point A to point B in my town. After I selected the correct *'Input Point Layer'* I needed to select the *'Order Field'* (the options being "Longitude", "Latitude", or "Intersection"). In order to have the line drawn in sequence with how I entered the points in the .csv file, I had to choose "Longitude" as the *Order Field*, or else the program connected dots out of sequence.

Does anyone have idea of why Longitude needs to be selected for the *'Order Field'*?

Comment: It seems that you do not have a real order field in your data. It means an attribute with growing numbers 1,2,3,4.... If your points are written ordered into your CSV file you do not need to select order field at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a field to get a simple ordered number for the entries in your table you can use the field calculator to make a new field and use the function/variable

```
 @row_number
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, this all quite new for me, so I'll have explore that.  Most of my curiosity lied with the part that "Latitude" and "Intersection" didn't produce the result I wanted.  Through my inexperience it seems quite random that "Longitude" needed to be selected for the Order Field. The points in the .csv don't sit in any type of numerical sequence either, rather in an order that shows how, on foot, to get from A to B.  I'm not anxious to learn why in any immediate time, I just figured I would see if anyone had an idea.

Comment: longitude and latitude could not be an orderfield to get your points to a path, imagine walking zig-zag...QGIS proposes any field for that - if this will make sense or not. Best is to have a time value for that